# Motherboard Information

Tags: c++, windows, hardware

I don't get good ways to do the things other than WINAPI (Slow... and hard).

So here i'll come with a request on how to get Motherboard Information, such as RAM Type (DDR, DDR2, DDR3), Manufacturer, Model, Southbridge, BIOS (Brand, Version, Date). RAM Channels #, RAM NB Frequency. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting hardware information you can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It can help you.

Comment: I heard that it's slow and hard to use, that's why i don't want it. :/

Comment: may be this topic will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262404/access-motherboard-information-without-using-wmi