# How to get the hardware info without using WMI?

Tags: winapi

I am programming an activation code for my application, I need to provide the key file with information about the licensed computer, I need to retrieve information about some devices like processor ID and DiskDrive Serial number, and the BIOS Serial as well ,, and so on with some devices, but these are the major ones.

I need to combine the method with another application programmed by another language so I cannot use WMI, but I can use winapi.

is there a way to fetch the physical data using winapi?if so, then how?

Comment: Sure  you can use WMI. You can get at that from any language.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thanks for replying, I don't mean C# or VB, I mean Flash or Java or C++ ..

Comment: If you can call Window API then you can use WMI. It's part of the Windows API.

Comment: That what I came to after having a nice conversation with the architect, could you please post this as an answer so I can check it as a solution for other readers? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, sorry I forgot tagging you in the previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to call Windows API functions, then you can use WMI. After all, the WMI interface is part of the Windows API.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [Win32_BIOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class and the [PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

Accessing motherboard information without WMI seems not to be doable with current means. Here you can find a similar question:
[Access Motherboard information without using WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262404/access-motherboard-information-without-using-wmi)